# Access PHP Logfile

Tags: php

is there  any "sexy" solution to access the php error_log from remote? Like implemented in Zend Server CE?

Or how to you handle it, if there is no SSH Access for the server users?

To clarify: it is our own server running on winXP :-)

Comment: it depends on wether you have permission or not on the server

Comment: SSH is available for windows as well - as well as a bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is - Just put error log in your www directory (public viewable) and you can then browse to it/download it (others can download/browse it,too!)

Comment: sure ;) but i think it is not "sexy" solution ,;)

Comment: Who cares if it's sexy or not? You asked"how", not "how to do it sexy way" ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your goals are but if you are only interested in handling the application errors and not server errors, you need to log them. PHP provides a function for setting global error handler where you can perform your logging : http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php , I usually log them in a database and read it using a password protected form. For many applications I include it in the administration interface under 'logs'. Making your error logs publicly visible  is not a good idea because of security concerns.

However this would not be helpful if you want to log server errors too eg: 404, 500 errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any hosting provider it's possible that error_log to be accessible via control panel.